# C# library on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, visual-studio

**FAIR WARNING:** I am a newbie to iOS and this may very well be a basic question.

I manage a PC desktop app that has a fairly comprehensive library written in C#. I want some of the library functionality to be available to a new iOS project that I am undertaking. So - what are some of the architectural possibilities for using my existing C# library with an iOS project?

I've done droid development and the answer there was to create some web services that use my C# library and then have the droid consume those services. I'm assuming that same approach would work with iOS (right???) but I'm wondering if there are other options out there?

Comment: There's an iOS port of .NET called [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) that will let you make iPhone apps in C#/.NET (well, Mono, but that should be sufficient), but it is fairly pricey.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the link. But to be clear, I'm willing to use XCode and all that good stuff, I don't necessarily want to replace the IDE. My interest is in being able to re-use my existing library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends what you mean to do:

- if you "consume" the library via SOA with your library at the server, then it should work fine, and iOS will never know about the library (or care)
- if, however, you mean to use the c# library on the iOS device, then you will *have* to use tools like MonoTouch - simply: iOS won't run a .NET dll without the supporting goo that tools like MonoTouch add (in particular, cross-compiling / AOT, and a different runtime)
- or, you could port your code to XCode manually

Comment: I also have the same situation as Jim Beam now. And your answer definitely gave me a clear idea of what is possible. Could you please let me know how can I port the C# code to Xcode? Thanks.

Comment: @EmptyStack 1: learn xcode, 2: start typing - sorry, there isn't much more to it than that

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @EmptyStack personally, I'd use MonoTouch / Xamarin in a heartbeat

Comment: Cool! But I can't use MonoTouch even in 60 heartbeats. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: This is certainly possible but in the reverse direction: C# can call into swift libraries